# DKIM in Marketing Cloud (Sender Authentication Package)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

I cannot find where can I put the DKIM in the exacttarget portal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no admin option to manage that. Exacttarget is doing that for you when you have the Sender Authentication Package. If you are using a domain not controlled by Exacttarget you should contact support how the application is working together with it.

Here's some documentation on the topic:https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/maintaining_your_own_dns_records_for_your_sending_domain/